# Complete JSON being outputed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

The output consists of the complete JSON, which is:

```
{reply:"Login success"}
```

The expected output is only the value for the key 'reply' ,

```
Login success
```

The required code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="resp" style="color:red;"></div>
```

**JS AJAX JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'tt.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'pass': pass , 'uname':uname},
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = data;
        }
        
});
```

**PHP**

```
$data['reply'] = "Login Success";
echo json_encode($data);
```

***Solutions tried to print the necessary data***

```
data[0]
data[1]
data[reply]
data.reply
data["reply"]
```

Comment: Some of the important part must be missing. Otherwise, there is no way that the output can ever be produced. Your PHP code suggests that it can only ever not contain "login success"

Comment: "The output" screenshot looks like its from a console error or something, if so, please show that full message

Comment: @Arrmaniac thank you for pointing out the typo error, fixed it

Comment: @WesleySmith It's not from a console, check the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP code you show us is not outputting what you say your expected output should be but, you can tell the AJAX call to expect JSON to be returned by adding `dataType: 'JSON',` to the properties of the call.

Then you can address the reply as `data.reply`

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'tt.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',                       // added this line
        data: {'pass': pass , 'uname':uname},
        success: function(data) {
            // then you can address the reply like this
            document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = data.reply;
        }

});
```

Comment: Sorry for that error, I fixed it, I'll try your solution in a moment

Comment: To also improve the server-end, the appropriate header ```"Content-Type: application/json"``` should be added.